# Magento Widget Grid only fires construct

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a magento module with an admin grid and I've encountered a strange problem.

The block is loading and so is the class that extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid, but the grid widget class is only firing the construct and not the _prepareCollection() or _prepareColumns() methods.

If I manually fire the _prepareCollection() method I get my collection so I know that's working. And I can confirm that all the layout xml's have loaded correctly.

With with nothing in the php, apache or magento error logs I'm a little stumped on where to look for the issue :(

Has anyone come across a similar scenario? and if so what was the cause? Does anyone have any suggestions on magento debugging when there are no errors in any of the logs?

Config xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<modules>
    <Fisheye_Enquiryforms>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Fisheye_Enquiryforms>
</modules>

<frontend>

    <routers>
        <fisheye_enquiryforms>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Fisheye_Enquiryforms</module>
                <frontName>enquiryforms</frontName>
            </args>
        </fisheye_enquiryforms>
    </routers>

    <layout>
        <updates>
            <fisheye_enquiryforms>
                <file>fisheye/enquiryforms/enquiryforms.xml</file>
            </fisheye_enquiryforms>  
        </updates>
    </layout>

</frontend>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Fisheye_Enquiryforms before="Mage_Adminhtml">Fisheye_Enquiryforms_Adminhtml</Fisheye_Enquiryforms>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <fisheye_enquiryforms>
                <file>fisheye/enquiryforms/enquiryforms.xml</file>
            </fisheye_enquiryforms>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>

<global>

    <blocks>
        <fisheye_enquiryforms>
            <class>Fisheye_Enquiryforms_Block</class>
        </fisheye_enquiryforms>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <fisheye_enquiryforms>
            <class>Fisheye_Enquiryforms_Helper</class> 
        </fisheye_enquiryforms>
    </helpers>

    <models>
        <fisheye_enquiryforms>
            <class>Fisheye_Enquiryforms_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>fisheye_enquiryforms_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </fisheye_enquiryforms>
        <fisheye_enquiryforms_mysql4>
            <class>Fisheye_Enquiryforms_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <catalogues><!-- tag must match lowercase model file name -->
                    <table>fisheye_enquiryforms_catalogues</table>
                </catalogues>
                <quotes><!-- tag must match lowercase model file name -->
                    <table>fisheye_enquiryforms_quotes</table>
                </quotes>
                <products><!-- tag must match lowercase model file name -->
                    <table>fisheye_enquiryforms_products</table>
                </products>
            </entities>              
        </fisheye_enquiryforms_mysql4>  
    </models>

    <resources>

        <fisheye_enquiryforms_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Fisheye_Enquiryforms</module>
            </setup>
        </fisheye_enquiryforms_setup>

    </resources>

</global>
```

enquiryforms.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<adminhtml_enquiryforms_catalogues_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="fisheye_enquiryforms/adminhtml_catalogues" name="enquiryforms.catalogues" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_enquiryforms_catalogues_index>
<adminhtml_enquiryforms_products_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="fisheye_enquiryforms/adminhtml_products" name="enquiryforms.products" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_enquiryforms_products_index>
<adminhtml_enquiryforms_quotes_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="fisheye_enquiryforms/adminhtml_quotes" name="enquiryforms.quotes" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_enquiryforms_quotes_index>
</layout>
```

Thanks in advance

Dave

Comment: are you calling `parent::__construct();` in the constructor?

Comment: Yeah, Grid __construct code is : parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('enquiryforms_catalogues_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('desc');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);

Comment: ok, can you show the config xml, and the structure of your module? have you declared your `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container` as well?

Comment: Ive edited the post to show the config and layout xml's. Ive got an edit i do to core / model / layouts/ update.php which tells me if the layout xmls are loading correctly, which they are, and this is supported by being able to put a die statement in the grids construct which executes. The module is huge so too much to post the whole thing, Im sure this is going to be something simple but I just cant see it :(

Comment: Slowly loosing the will to live with this, I cant find anything wrong and I've scoured the web for every layout debugging technique I can find :( Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after messing around with this for ages I decided to reactivate an old module I'd deactivated a while back in System > Config > Advanced to compare configs, only to find that one of my colleges had kindly been in and disabled all of the development modules to do some testing on a 3rd party module issue. That would explain why it just stopped rendering and also why I was getting no errors. I would like to thank Javier for all the help yesterday and appologise for my Megento noobness lol :) Another Magento lesson learned!

Thanks,

Dave B

Comment: you just saved my ass i was having the same issue, I spent 3 hours messing with the code before i found this

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, I hope it helps:
`company/modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Myblock.php`:

```
<?php
class Company_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Myblock extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'company_modulename';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_mycontroller';
        $this->_headerText = 'My Block';
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }
}
```

`company/modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Myblock/Grid.php`:

```
<?php
class Company_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Myblock_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('company_myblockGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }
    /**
     * Add custom column to the grid
     *
     */
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        // your stuff
        parent::setCollection($collection);
    }
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
       // your stuff
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        // your stuff
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

And then, from the controller:
`company/modulename/controllers/Adminhtml/Mycontroller.php`:

```
public function myblockgridAction()
{
    $this->_title('My block grid');
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('company_modulename/adminhtml_myblock'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

In your case, if you load it from the layout, should be the same.

Comment: My setup is identical to yours, I've now tried removing the layout xml's and calling the block from the controller as you suggested but I get the same result... Header and footer, no grid or page title and no errors :/ So frustrating! Thanks for the help so far tho :)

Comment: Now that you mention this, I think I had the same issue once, the block was being instantiated (construct was being called), but it wasn't being "rendered" for some reason... I wish I could remember how I fixed it! I'll get back to you if I can recall it...

Comment: If you have XDEBUG, I would suggest to place a breakpoint in the constructor of the block and see if you can find any clue. Also comparing the trace with another (working) grid could help.

Comment: Have you tried in your layout, replacing `adminhtml_enquiryforms_catalogues_index` by `enquiryforms_adminhtml_catalogues_index`? And so on?

Comment: I'll have a go at that when i get in tomorrow morning, not sure if its going to do anything as the grids constructor is firing so paths look correct, but worth a go lol :)