# Magento admin grid was not displaying only header title and add button are present

Tags: php, xml, magento

Thanks to @PHP Weblineindia for sharing a link for this tutorial http://navaneeth.me/creating-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/#comment-8147.

I followed almost every details given by this tutorial however I can't display the table grid.

UPDATE: <strike>Upon Debugging my model collection has a problem</strike>

Another UPDATE: I update all the resource model and collection and extend them to this

**Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract** -> resource model

**Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract** -> Collection model

The good thing is that. **I can now add new data to the database.**

BUT the main problem still the same, **no grid displayed**.

I've tried simple data retrieve in magento front end but it give me **Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object**.

I'm still new to magento and there are lot of mysteries that I need to discover.

MODEL

app/code/local/Rts/Pmadmin/Model/Pmadmin.php

```
class Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Pmadmin extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('pmadmin/pricematrix');
}
}
```

app/code/local/Rts/Pmadmin/Model/Mysql4/Resource/Pmadmin.php

```
class Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Mysql4_Resource_Pmadmin extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract {
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('pmadmin/pmadmin', 'pmadmin_id');
}
}
```

app/code/local/Rts/Pmadmin/Model/Mysql4/Resource/Collection.php

```
class Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Mysql4_Resource_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {
public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('pmadmin/pmadmin');
}
}
```

These are the codes.

UPDATED config.xml

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <pmadmin>
            <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Helper</class>
        </pmadmin>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <pmadmin>
            <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Block</class>
        </pmadmin>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <pmadmin>
            <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>pmadmin_resource</resourceModel>
        </pmadmin>
        <pmadmin_resource>
            <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <pmadmin>
                    <table>pmadmin</table>
                </pmadmin>
            </entities>
        </pmadmin_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <pmadmin_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Rts_Pmadmin</module>
               <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Mysql4_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </pmadmin_setup>
        <pmadmin_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </pmadmin_write>
        <pmadmin_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </pmadmin_read>
    </resources>
    </global>
```

UPDATE: Content block

```
class Rts_Pmadmin_Block_Adminhtml_Pmadmin_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('pmadmingrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('pmadmin_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('pmadmin/pmadmin')->getCollection();
    // print_r($collection); exit();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumn('pricematrix_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('pmadmin')->__('ID'),
        'align' => 'right',
        'width' => '10px',
        'index' => 'pricematrix_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('title', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('pmadmin')->__('Title'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'title',
        'width' => '50px',
    ));


    $this->addColumn('short_description', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('pmadmin')->__('Description'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'short_description',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('file_path', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('pmadmin')->__('File Path'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'file_path',
    ));


    $this->addColumn('customer_group', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('pmadmin')->__('Customer Group'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'customer_group',
    ));


    $this->addColumn('creation_time', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('pmadmin')->__('Posted On'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'creation_time',
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}


public function getRowUrl($row) {
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
}

public function getGridUrl()
{
  return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}
}
```

PROBLEM:

1. No grid is displayed only the header title and the add button
2. When click add button, the forms are displayed however I can't add new Item
3. Model Collection return "bool(false)" after var dump

QUESTION:

Can you help me spot the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Way too much to read, especially after I saw you followed *almost* every detail....

Comment: @ElefantPhace I appologize.

Comment: Just try to print collection in grid file is there you get collection or not.      Go to Block->Adminhtml->Pmadmin->Grid.php
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('pmadmin/pmadmin')->getCollection();
    print_r($collection); die;
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

Comment: I've tried this however it did'nt show anything. I updated also my models and I can now add new data to the database.

Comment: Hello Rodge, I think there is problem with your config.xml file follow all the steps as per given tutorial link.
In your config.xml make <model> </model> and <resource> </resource> should be same as tutorial. I will suggest you to follow same copy as given link.

Comment: Hello @PHP Weblineindia, I updated my config.xml. The code is almost the same. On the frontend, tried this $test = Mage::getModel('pmadmin/pmadmin');var_dump($test->getData('title')); and returns NULL.

Comment: If you have a problem with your grid but the buttons are displayed, it means that you are loading the container but not the content block. Please provide blocks + controller

Comment: @Nicolas D, I already updated and included the content grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your Model folder structure. I'm not an expert on magento but I think you separate your resource model and collection model into separate folder.

Based on @Nicolas D answer, I also encounter this problem on magento 1.9.1. It also took me several days to find out the solution.

Yes, @Nicolas D is right, you have to put your resource folder on Mysql4 folder. However, under Mysql4 folder, you have to create a folder the same name as your module name and put your Collection.php model.

For example:

Instead of

```
Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Mysql4_Resource
```

Make it

```
Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Mysql4_Pmadmin
```

Also! Don't forget to update your config.xml and other file related to your changes.

```
<models>
    <pmadmin>
        <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>pmadmin_resource</resourceModel>
    </pmadmin>
    <pmadmin_resource>
        <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
            <pmadmin>
                <table>pmadmin</table>
            </pmadmin>
        </entities>
    </pmadmin_resource>
</models>
<resources>
    <pmadmin_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Rts_Pmadmin</module>
           <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Mysql4_Pmadmin_Mysql4_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </pmadmin_setup>
    <pmadmin_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </pmadmin_write>
    <pmadmin_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </pmadmin_read>
</resources>
```

I don't know if this is a magento bug but this is how we solved our problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem once on my old magento version, which seems also to be your case, and the collection was false due to that :

You have to add Mysql4 in you classes names.
Config:

```
<pmadmin_resource>
    <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Mysql4_Resource</class>
    <entities>
        <pmadmin>
            <table>pmadmin</table>
        </pmadmin>
    </entities>
</pmadmin_resource>
```

Models:

```
Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Mysql4_Resource_Pricematrix_Collection
Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Mysql4_Resource_Pricematrix
```

Comment: yes exactly, my models fails to load data but it allow me to add new data on the database. Is it a magento bug? I updated the code however it didn't display the grid table.

Comment: did you updated well your model classes also on code? it is not updated here

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update the post. I updated all my models and the config.xml but no luck

Comment: no errors in logs i guess?
if not, try to debug one by one your widget block functions to see what is loaded and what is not

Comment: Yes no error logs. I don't have the debugging skills in magento but I will try this technique from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320628/magento-widget-grid-only-fires-construct    ---- and ------   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784117/magento-how-to-debug-blank-white-screen

Comment: basically, var_dump('my_function) in each function is enough sometimes to understand

Comment: I tried to debug the grid content block and it turns out that the model collection is returning Null  or Bool(false).